# AngularJS and Typescript with SingalR

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, signalr, signalr-hub

I have the following code:

Controller:

```
class MyController {
    private names: string[];
    private myHub:any;
    constructor(){

        this.myHub = $.connection.myHub;
        this.myHub.client.clientMethod = (name:string) =>{
            // "name" gets added to the this.names array but does not get displayed in the view.
            this.names.push(name);
        });
        $.connection.hub.start().done(()=>{
            this.myHub.server.myServerMethod();
        });

        // "test name" gets added to the this.name array and is viewed in the view
        this.names.push("test name");

    }

}
```

View:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as c">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="n in c.names">{{n}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The code in the controller works fine. The SignalR Hub is doing exactly what it's supposed to do. The "clientMethod" gets called from the server and the "this.names.push(name)" gets executed as expected and pushes the name into the array. But for some reason the names do not get displayed in the View. If I physically push a string into the this.names array it gets displayed without a problem.

Could this be a problem with the "this" scope of the controller?

What do you think I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You need scope.$apply() inside clientMethod as it is run outside angular context

Comment: 'Could this be a problem with the "this" scope of the controller?' No shit. Have you tried to log the value of `this`? I really wish people would learn JS before jumping into Typescript.

Comment: I am not using "scope" in my controller. I am using the "MyController as c" as recommended by the Angular docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

Comment: @StefanBaiu you have to ask to learn mate, so calm down

Comment: @StefanBaiu OP is using [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) so `this` (it will be lexical `this`) is not a problem but digest cycle is.

Comment: @PSL: you are right. The event is happening outside of angular world.

Comment: This seems like one of those `$scope.$apply()` duplicate question.. NOM :)

Comment: thanks StefanBaiu and PSL. Ok, does this mean I will need to inject $scope, correct?

Comment: @ZeroOne Alternatively you can use a wrapper, which will be much cleaner. [Here is one](https://github.com/JustMaier/angular-signalr-hub).

Comment: yep, create a service and inject $scope there

Comment: @PSL I will give that wrapper a go. For now, I injected $scope and applied a digest, that worked. This always catches me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
  this.myHub.client.clientMethod = (name:string) =>{
            // "name" gets added to the this.names array but does not get displayed in the view.
            this.names.push(name);
        });
```

In the context of a `$scope.$apply()`:

```
  this.myHub.client.clientMethod = (name:string) =>{
            scope.$apply(()=>{
                this.names.push(name);
            });
        });
```

Ofcourse this means you need to take `scope` in as a constructor parameter.

Alternatively you can wrap all the signalr stuff into a service that uses `$rootScope`

Comment: Yes, I eventually added $rootScope to my signalR service